# Graphic Novel/Comic. Regards a fire/demonic king in medieval times who was revived and wreaks havoc on the land

Tags: story-identification

The comic begins with a siege on a castle by orcs(I think?) and the king, who had been bent on dominating the land, realizes the battle is lost. He becomes mortally wounded and dies. In the future (still medieval times), acolytes revive him and he takes on a fiery/demonic appearance having new powers. He returns to his mission of conquering the land, slaughtering innocent villagers. An archer's family is murdered in the process and she seeks revenge. She attempts to assassinate him but he cannot be killed by conventional weapons much to her horror. Then I don't remember the rest of the story...Ring a bell anyone?